# bokeh hbar_stack not rendering properly when using datetimes

Tags: python-3.x, django, bokeh

i'm trying to plot a hbar_stack with datetimes in x axis with no luck. i've done normal hbar plots with datetimes before with no problems so it's has to be something with the hbar_stack.
Here is the code with some static data:

```
start_date = datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 10, 10, 26, 15, 240666)
end_date = datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 10, 13, 27, 33, 741238)
tasks = ['task 1', 'task 2', 'task 3', 'task 4']
status = ['status_1', 'status_2', 'status_3', 'status_4']
exports = {'tasks': tasks, 'status_1': [datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 10, 13, 26, 59, 531234),
                                        datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 10, 13, 25, 16, 666837),
                                        datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 10, 10, 37, 16, 368927),
                                        datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 10, 10, 26, 15, 240666)],
           'status_2': [None, datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 10, 13, 27, 33, 741238),
                        datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 10, 11, 37, 7, 629667),
                        datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 10, 10, 27, 5, 540767)],
           'status_3': [None, None, None, datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 10, 10, 54, 17, 738024)],
           'status_4': [None, None, None, datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 10, 11, 2, 15, 196620)]}

p = figure(y_range=tasks, x_range=[start_date, end_date], x_axis_type='datetime', title="Tasks timeline",
          tools=["hover,pan,reset,save,wheel_zoom"], tooltips=None)
p.xaxis.formatter = DatetimeTickFormatter(
    days=["%m-%d-%Y"],
    months=["%m-%d-%Y"],
    years=["%m-%d-%Y"],
)
p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = radians(30)
p.hbar_stack(status, y='tasks', height=0.2, color=Spectral[11][:len(status)], source=ColumnDataSource(exports))
```

As one can see from the data the datetimes are minutes apart but it renders with years of difference. On hovering the data(x, y) the x value is not showing a date, instead it's showing a big number like 1.589e+12. Any help is appreciated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rO19z.png)

Comment: *"renders with years of difference."* Your linked image does not show that at all? The range start is on 2020-07-10 and range end is one day later on 2020-07-11. As for formatting datetime hover tooltips, that is explained in the docs: https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html#formatting-tooltip-fields

Comment: That said, I am not sure any stacking is appropriate for datetimes. Stack operations explicitly *add values together* to get new positions. What does it mean to add two datetimes together? It woudl make more sense to talk about datetime *intervals*, not the datetimes themselves.

Comment: @bigreddot well the diffence is only minutes... in the image is only showing the range i provided, when scrolling the graph the bars extend for years...

Comment: As I mentioned, adding actual datetime values together is not a sensical thing to do. The things you stack need to be the differences between the datetimes, not the actual datetimes themselves. The datetimes represent the number of milliseconds since epoch start (January 1, 1970) so "adding" them adds years at a time.

Comment: @bigreddot i've tried creating a stack using p.rect() but calculating the width as the time interval it's kind of tricky and they overlap

Comment: It's simpler than that, see below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
dts = [
    datetime(2020, 7, 10, 13, 26, 59, 531234),
    datetime(2020, 7, 10, 13, 25, 16, 666837),
    datetime(2020, 7, 10, 10, 37, 16, 368927),
    datetime(2020, 7, 10, 10, 26, 15, 240666)
]

# because the datetimes are in reverse order
ends = dts[0:-1]
starts = dts[1:]

p = figure(plot_height=350, x_axis_type="datetime", y_range=["a", "b", "c"])
p.hbar(y=["b", "b", "b"], left=starts, right=ends, 
       line_color="white", fill_color=["red", "blue", "orange"])
p.xaxis.formatter.hours = ["%b %Y %H:%M"]

show(p)
```

which yields:

[image]

Comment: what version are you using? It renders properly but I'm getting no results

Comment: well at the end i had a similar code using hbar but i discarded it because it was not rendering... guess the problem was in the x_range, i removed it following your code and it worked.

Comment: I would expect setting a fixed range using datetimes to work, please [open an issue](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues) with a minimal reproducer if it is not.

Comment: Woot! Just what I needed